# how to add custom bar button item to navigation bar in AddressBookUI application like edit in place of cancel

Tags: iphone, addressbook, addressbookui

I can not understand  why navigation bar is not going to add any button   other than cancel button  in Following code
   this kind of thing done in Viber application so it is possible

```
 ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController     alloc] init];
picker.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:91.0/256.0 green:72.0/256.0 blue:110.0/256.0 alpha:1.0];
//picker.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
[picker.navigationBar setHidden:NO];
picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
// Display only a person's phone, email, and birthdate
NSArray *displayedItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonPhoneProperty], 
                           [NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonEmailProperty],
                           [NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonBirthdayProperty], nil];

//picker.navigationBarHidden=TRUE;
picker.displayedProperties = displayedItems;
//UIBarButtonItem *addbutton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(AddContact)];          
   //   picker.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.rightBarButtonItem = addbutton;

[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:NO];
[picker release];
//[addbutton release];
```

can anybody help please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

refer [this](http://www.scott-sherwood.com/ios5-removing-the-cancel-button-on-abpeoplepickernavigationcontroller/) article it demonstrates how to add custom button on `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController`

Answer (score 2):

i can show you how to add custom button to navigation bar. Use this code if this is helpful,

```
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Done.png"];

    UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

    [aButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    aButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);

    UIBarButtonItem *aBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:aButton];

    [aButtonaddTarget:selfaction:@selector(navigatehome)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = aBarButtonItem;

    [aBarButtonItem release];
```